# Extends a base class vs Inject it in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular 4 app and I came to a situation where I have a **htpInterceptor** base service class which has Typescript generic GET, POST and DELETE functions.  I want all my angular services to use this base class. Now I am not sure whether I should inject this base service into all my services OR I should extends all my service class with this base service class.

Should I use,
`export class AuthService extends HttpInterceptorService`
            OR
`constructor(private _interceptor:HttpInterceptorService) { }`

What is the difference ( pros and cons) between these two approach.

Following is my base service class,

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    get<T>(relativeUrl: ApiUrl): Observable<T> {
        const baseUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl + environment.apiLearnerUrl;
        let apiUrl = baseUrl + relativeUrl.toString();
        return this._http.get(apiUrl).map(res => <T>res.json());
    }
    post<T>(relativeUrl: ApiUrl, inputData: any): Observable<T> {
        const baseUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl + environment.apiLearnerUrl;
        let apiUrl = baseUrl + relativeUrl.toString();
        if (inputData === undefined) {
            return this._http.post(apiUrl, undefined).map(res => <T>res.json());
        }
        else {
            return this._http.post(apiUrl, inputData).map(res => <T>res.json());
        }

    }

    delete<T>(relativeUrl: string): Observable<T> {
        const baseUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl + environment.apiLearnerUrl;
        let apiUrl = baseUrl + relativeUrl;
        return this._http.delete(apiUrl).map(res => <T>res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered moving to the newer `HttpClient` that is available in Angular 4.3 and higher, and using the readily available [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/guide/http#advanced-usage)?

Comment: @R. Richards  our project is still  using angular 4.2  we are planning to migrate it to 4.3 in coming months though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros and cons depend on the case. But the code above is classic composition vs inheritance dilemma. And the recommended approach is generally [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

In this case `HttpInterceptorService` is expected to work as extended replacement for `Http`. So it should be *injected* instead of `Http`.

If `AuthService` is supposed to implement `HttpInterceptorService` and extend its functionality (e.g. wrap existing methods and add authentication headers), it should be *inherited* from `HttpInterceptorService`.

Answer (score 1):

With an imported service you rely on Angular's DI, you decide on what level to include it.

Using `extends` relies on native ES6 syntax so it may be more portable.

So I guess it is mostly a question of preference and whether you think you might use your code outside Angular.

Also with extends you will have to call `super()` in every constructor that calls the parent class. This doesn't feel like the Angular way if you care about that...

Comment: I prefer to inject instead of inheriting it but do you think, there is any difference in terms of performance OR any side effect of using one approach vs another.  I am adding my base service class code as well in my question.

Comment: My preference would be to do everything the Angular way in an Angular project. I doubt there is any significant performance difference.

Comment: I will keep this question open for now to get some more clarification on it. Have added the base service code, in case, it might help for someone to throw some more light. Thanks for your inputs though.